# Express vs Spring Boot MVC Controllers and Services

Tags: node.js, spring, spring-boot, express

I have a background with a spring boot, but I started learning NodeJS (Express). In Express, the business logic is included in the controllers and there are no services, but there are routes, that resemble the controllers in Spring Boot.

Which components represents the controllers, services and repositories in Express?
For example, in spring boot, the request parameters are validated in the controller and the business logic is executed in the service. However, in Express I have the feeling, that the both operations are done by the controller.
Is there a cheat sheet for express as a Spring Boot developer.

Comment: While I don't have experience with Spring Boot it sounds like it is an entire MVC framework. Compared to it, ExpressJS is not the same, it's just a backend app framework. If you want an MVC framework for Node try something like SailsJS.

I'm not affiliated with any library mentioned in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Designing the flow and structure of your backend is up to YOU as a developer – not the language. Nothing is stopping you from designing a backend using express where the request parameters are validated in the controller and business logic is executed in service files. As a matter of fact, every Express API I have built follows that exact process.

I'll link an API that I created, but feel free to use any of the following resources:

1. https://github.com/sidd-mittal/REST-API
2. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rest-api-design-best-practices-build-a-rest-api/

TLDR; building you're API structure is language-agnostic, choose whatever suits your wants and needs.